# What Does [-/M] Indicates after filename in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, netbeans-8

While Working on Java project in NetBeans I found one source file ended with the symbol **filename.java [-/M]**. My question is what [-/M] indicates? Does it functionality of Language or IDE?

You can see this in following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I think you are right @assylias . I use git for source control. but I search on google no where found specif detail about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says that the file has been modified vs. what is in your source control system. For example if you are using git, see [this page](https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/kb/docs/ide/git/#_file_status_labels).

You can turn the labels off in View > Show Versioning Labels.